# Recycler View with "Load More Results" Button

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a requirement of displaying 10 elements in the list at once. After loading 10 elements user will have "Load More Results" button. On click of this button it will fetch another 10 elements from the server. If initially the total no. of elements are less then 10, it should not display "Load More Results" button.

So, I want to develop this using Recycler View, but I am not able to do this.
Please guide me.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `"but I am not able to do this"` so what have you tried so far?

Comment: first add 10 items in array list, after clicking Load More Results add 10 more items into array list and do `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: @Redman Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your xml make loadButton visibility gone.

In your activity class when your setting data to the adapter in API callback method, just check

```
    if(list.size()>=10) {
    loadButton.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    } else {
    loadButton.setVisibility(GONE);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: If it's solved your problem mark it as correct answer @AbdulRahaman

Answer (score 1):

You can start with something like this.

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Load More"
                android:visibility="visible" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Implementation logic up to you ;)

Answer (score 0):

[RecyclerView.OnScrollListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnScrollListener.html)

First implement `OnScrollListener` on your recyclerview. You can get the last item from on scroll listener and put a button named LOAD MORE. Just make it visible when last item of `RecyclerView` you got.